# Proxy an HTTP Live Stream via a secure, tokenized URL in Java

Tags: java, http, proxy, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to proxy an HTTP Live Stream through a Java servlet.  Essentially, the proxy will act as the endpoint for the encrypted, tokenized URL.  The servlet will then decrypt the URL and, if valid, request the HTTP Live Stream video from the streaming server and return the stream to the client.  Obviously, I never want the actual URL to the streaming content to be sent to the client, nor for the client to access it directly - I always want the stream to pass through the proxy.

Since the HTTP Live Stream is just HTTP, I assumed a simple HTTP proxy would work. However, I have not had any luck.  I have gotten it as far as the browser knowing to display the video player (it's receiving the correct MIME type), and I can see the network request grow to the size of the video stream.  Unfortunately, the video never actually plays.

Ideally, I would love to use an existing product (open source preferable), but I'm happy to roll my own if none is available (although I can't imagine I'm the only one who wants to do this).

Any thoughts/suggestions/solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like your approach is sound. Can you provide more debugging information? Also, are you talking about HLS or progressive download?

Comment: Thanks.  It is HLS using the lighttpd server.  The proxy server itself is running in Tomcat 7.  I will try to get more debug information.